# Fixed header and footer on a page?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to have a fixed header and footer on windows phone page? I am using plain XAML, not using any thirdparty controls.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Sure, here is the code and the layout

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="I AM HEADER" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="56"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" >
        <TextBlock Text="Main content goes here. Main content goes here. " TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="56"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="I AM FOOTER" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="56"/>

</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want something that you can use over and over, I would suggest creating a custom control. This control can easily be used by any of your pages.

Custom Control:

```
public class HeaderFooterControl : ContentControl
{
    public object Header
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Header.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(object), typeof(HeaderFooterControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public object Footer
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(FooterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FooterProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Header.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FooterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Footer", typeof(object), typeof(HeaderFooterControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    // TODO: Templates for Header and Footer
}
```

Xaml for Custom Control:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyLocalNamespace">
    <Style TargetType="controls:HeaderFooterControl">
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="Header info"/>
        <Setter Property="Footer" Value="Footer info"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:HeaderFooterControl">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Footer}" Grid.Row="2"/>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

You would then use the control if you page like such:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyLocalNamespace"
    <!-- Other parts of the page to declare (eg: FontSize, Foreground, etc)
    <controls:HeaderFooterControl Header="Hello Header!" Footer="Bottom of page!">
        <!-- Other content for your page here! -->
    </controls:HeaderFootControl>
```

You can add to this solution by also having a HeaderTemplate and FooterTemplate that can be set. You can find out more about Custom Controls [here](http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2012/02/06/Why-Custom-Controls-are-underrated.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

sure the default grid on a page is 2 rows. make it 3.. top and bottom rows set to auto height.. middle set to *